# How to find if result of math expression is correct in string?

Tags: c, string, math

I have little problem to find how to check if result of math expression is correct given as a string, for example 2+2=4-->OK ; 4*4=10-->false.

I have something like that, but it only calculate given string but not validate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

   int eval(char *);

int main()
{
char expr[100];
int x;
fgets(expr, sizeof(expr), stdin);
x = eval(expr);
printf("Answer: %d\n", x);  
}

int eval(char *str)
{
char *p;
int lhs, rhs;
char op;
int r = 0;
lhs = strtol(str, &p, 10);
while(*p == ' ') p++;
op = *p++;
rhs = strtol(p, &p, 10);
switch(op) {
    case '+': r = lhs + rhs; break;
    case '-': r = lhs - rhs; break;
    case '*': r = lhs * rhs; break;
    case '/': r = lhs / rhs; break;
}
return r;
}
```

Comment: But you're almost there! Read the next character in the same way that you read the operator. Raise an error if it isn't an equals sign, otherwise read the expected result into another variable and compare it with `r`. Or are you asking how to validate compound expressions like `6 + 3*7`?

Comment: No just 4+2 or 3*7, I only needed some logic how to know how can I take that result of arithmetic operatorion and know if it is okay or wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you might looking for a code like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int eval(char *);

int main()
{
    char expr[100];
    int x;
    // fgets(expr, sizeof(expr), stdin);
    gets(expr);
    x = eval(expr); // if function returns zero means the expression is false else true.
    if(x)
    printf("True : %d\n", x);
    else 
    printf("false expression");
}

int eval(char *str)
{
    char *p;
    int lhs, rhs;
    char op;
    int r = 0;
    lhs = strtol(str, &p, 10);
    while (*p == ' ')
        p++;
    op = *p++;
    rhs = strtol(p, &p, 10);
    switch (op)
    {
    case '+':
        r = lhs + rhs;
        break;
    case '-':
        r = lhs - rhs;
        break;
    case '*':
        r = lhs * rhs;
        break;
    case '/':
        r = lhs / rhs;
        break;
    }

    // modified part
    int right; // to store rhs of exp.
    op = *p++; // assign '=' 
    right = strtol(p, NULL, 10); // assigning next int.
    if (r == right)//checking if LHS = RHS.
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

you had quite solved it. I just made some little changes hope you understand the edits I have made.
thank you.

Comment: But there is trouble when I am trying to make it until EOF( or NULL in this case), cant pass char type to it. Is there some way to overtype it?

Comment: sorry bro, but I'm also new to programming hence doesn't know much about file handling.